# Why is input attribute called hundreds of times when evaluating a function

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, typescript, disabled-input

I use an attribute by control access to check if a field should be enabled or disabled.

So i have something like this :

```
<input matInput type="text" #name="ngModel" name="application.name" [ngModel]="application?.name" (ngModelChange)="application.name=$event"
              placeholder="Nom de l'application" required [disabled]="isDisabled([permissions.applications.any.update, permissions.applications.own.update], 'name')"[appUnique]="application" [listElem]="applications" key="name" maxlength="255">
```

The `isDisabled` function is called hundreds times when the input is displayed and each action on the form triggers something like 12 or 32 additional calls.

That causes my browser to freeze.

Any idea why this behavior is occuring? Is it ZoneJS which cause this?

How can make just one called to this function?

Edit: Directive implementation

```
/**
 * Check if the component should be disabled
 */
@Directive({
  selector: "[appIsDisabled]"
})
export class IsDisabledDirective implements OnInit {
  // Listof permission to check 
  @Input("appIsDisabled") permissions: PermissionInterface[];
  // The resource id to be access
  @Input() resourceId: number;
  // The resource type to be access
  @Input() resourceType: string;
   // Attribute to be check(eg: name, firstname... for a user resource)
  @Input() attribute: string;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private el: ElementRef, private utilsService: UtilsService, private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (!this.authService.hasPermission(this.permissions, this.resourceId, this.resourceType, this.attribute)) {
      this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, "disabled", "disabled");
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: There are some good articles about this behavior : https://blog.appverse.io/why-it-is-a-bad-idea-to-use-methods-in-the-html-templates-with-angular-2-30d49f0d3b16

Comment: Ok, i was aware of angular cycle but do not know that it apply to attribute too. Txt. I will find another solution to control the disabled state of the input. If someone as suggestion, it would be great

Answer (score 1):

You better not doing property binding to a method to avoid too frequently checking status.

Here are my suggestions:

1. Use **RxJS** to track changes.

   - Try to detect your **permissions.applications.any.update** changes and wrapping into a Observable.  You can subscribe this from the `ngOnInit` hook in your component.
2. Use **Pure Pipe** to detect changes.

   - Try to move your `isDisabled` method to a pure pipe component.
3. Use **setInterval** to check status changes periodically.

Comment: This is not applicable in my case. Status is always the same. Permissions are retrieved on the user connection. I change my code to use a directive that add disabled attribute. Now i need to find a way to tell the mat-form-field to take into account this change.

Comment: Even you are using directive, you still have to facing change detection issues.  Can you share your `isDisabled` implementation?

Comment: I test it, method in the onInit of the directive is only called once. Input get it's disabled attribute but this is not apply on the view as Mat-form-field does not detect the chance. I update my question to post my directive

Comment: @Scandinave Does your `this.authService.hasPermission()` only need execute once after the component been initialized?

Comment: When using a directive yes.

Comment: No, I mean do you "NEED" it been execute only once?  I thought you need check this periodically.

Comment: Just only once. The disabled state is computed based on the user permissions. So this will not change until reconnection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172619/discussion-between-will-huang-and-scandinave).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is your method is executed by angular in changes detection algorithm. Angular scans every binding to detect changes and act accordingly and it does it fairly often and it can happen many times per single event. You need to learn about [this process](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html) and how to [minimize it](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2016/05/04/angular-2-best-practices-change-detector-performance/). This is a big subject and going into details in SO answer is not appropriate, but three tips from the referenced article are:

> Have less DOM. This is a critically important piece of the puzzle. If DOM elements aren’t visible, you should remove them from the DOM by using *ngIf instead of simply hiding elements with CSS. As the saying goes, the fastest code is code that is not run—and the fastest DOM is DOM that doesn’t exist.
>
> Make your expressions faster. Move complex calculations into the ngDoCheck lifecycle hook, and refer to the calculated value in your view. Cache results to complex calculations as long as possible.
>
> Use the OnPush change detection strategy to tell Angular 2 there have been no changes. This lets you skip the entire change detection step on most of your application most of the time.

Comment: I think put things in the `ngDoCheck` lifecycle hook is not a good option.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i found a solution to my problem, 
I pre-calculate the state off all fields in the component side. 
So for a user profile this is my function :

```
 computesFieldsDisableState() {
    this.disabled = {
      thumbnails: !this.authService.hasPermission([this.permissions.profil.update], this.user.id, "user", "thumbnails"),
      name: !this.authService.hasPermission([this.permissions.profil.update], this.user.id, "user", "name"),
      firstname: !this.authService.hasPermission([this.permissions.profil.update], this.user.id, "user", "firstname"),
      password: !this.authService.hasPermission([this.permissions.profil.update], this.user.id, "user", "password"),
      email: !this.authService.hasPermission([this.permissions.profil.update], this.user.id, "user", "email"),
      roles: !this.authService.hasPermission([this.permissions.profil.update], this.user.id, "user", "roles"),
    };
  }
```

Now i just have to use `[disabled]="disabled.thumbnails"` to get the state of the field.

Thank you all for you answers.